# "git log --name-status" with libgit2

Tags: c, git, git-log, libgit2

I want to implement git log --name-status with libgit2. I am fairly new to libgit2.
So far I've implemented "git log".

With git_commit_author I get:
-commit hash
-date
-author

With git_commit_message:
-commit message

```
int log() {

    diffopts.pathspec.strings;
    diffopts.pathspec.count = 0;
    if (diffopts.pathspec.count > 0)
        check_lg2(git_pathspec_new(&ps, &diffopts.pathspec),
            "Building pathspec", NULL);

    for (; !git_revwalk_next(&oid, this->walker); git_commit_free(commit)) {
        check_lg2(git_commit_lookup(&commit, this->repo, &oid),
            "Failed to look up commit", NULL);

        parents = (int)git_commit_parentcount(commit);

        if (diffopts.pathspec.count > 0) {
            int unmatched = parents;

            if (parents == 0) {
                git_tree* tree;
                check_lg2(git_commit_tree(&tree, commit), "Get tree", NULL);
                if (git_pathspec_match_tree(
                    NULL, tree, GIT_PATHSPEC_NO_MATCH_ERROR, ps) != 0)
                    unmatched = 1;
                git_tree_free(tree);
                }
            }
        }

        print_commit(commit);

        if (show_diff) {
            git_tree* a = NULL, * b = NULL;
            git_diff* diff = NULL;

            if (parents > 1)
                continue;
            check_lg2(git_commit_tree(&b, commit), "Get tree", NULL);
            if (parents == 1) {
                git_commit* parent;
                check_lg2(git_commit_parent(&parent, commit, 0), "Get parent", NULL);
                check_lg2(git_commit_tree(&a, parent), "Tree for parent", NULL);
                git_commit_free(parent);
            }

            check_lg2(git_diff_tree_to_tree(
                &diff, git_commit_owner(commit), a, b, &diffopts),
                "Diff commit with parent", NULL);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_commit(git_commit* commit)
{
    git_commit_message(commit);
    const git_signature* sig = git_commit_author(commit)
    sig->name;
    sig->email;
    sig->when;
}
```

How can I add this options to log command?
Thank you

Comment: I would like to do something like this [link with git log name status in c#](http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-log-name-status)

Comment: Use git_diff_foreach with a file callback on the "diff" you populated with git_diff_tree_to_tree. In the file callback, you can get the status of the file from git_diff_delta->status which returns git_delta_t.